# Как инициализировать несколько slick слайдеров с одинаковым классом?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Нужно сделать что бы на страницу можно было добавлять любое количество слайдеров с одинаковым классом. Как сделать что бы все слайдера работали независимо друг от друга имея одинаковый класс?

```
$('.sliderBox').slick({
      autoplay: true,
      prevArrow: $('.sliderLeftBtn'),
      nextArrow: $('.sliderRightBtn'),
      dots: true,
      appendDots: $('.sliderControl'),
});


$('.sliderBox').slick({
      autoplay: true,
      prevArrow: $('.sliderLeftBtn'),
      nextArrow: $('.sliderRightBtn'),
      dots: true,
      appendDots: $('.sliderControl'),
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.sliderBox').each(...)
```

[each](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: Sliders are initialized without this, but what about the dots and control buttons? they apply and work only for the last slider.

Comment: $('.sliderBox') - возвращает массив (Array like object).

Comment: Сделайте вывод console.log($('.sliderBox')) и вы увидите, на какой объект вы назначаете конфиг слайдера. Селектор $('.sliderBox') возвращает МАССИВ эллементов, к КАЖДОМУ из которых нужно применить конфиг, в то время, как в документации slick, насколько я помню, примеры построены на ID селекторе, который возвращает не массив, а объект! ($('#slider') - вернет объект)

Comment: Сделал Object { 0: div#sliderBox1.sliderBox.slick-initialized.slick-slider.slick-dotted, 1: div#sliderBox2.sliderBox.slick-initialized.slick-slider.slick-dotted, length: 2, prevObject: {…} }

Comment: $('.sliderBox').slick({})    -- если сделать так то все слайдеры работают, но кнопки и точки работают только для последнего слайдера. Как это решить не знаю.

Comment: $('.sliderBox') возвращает массив элементов - все ваши слайдеры с классом sliderBox. Вам нужно ПЕРЕБРАТЬ этот массив и каждому слайдеру назначить ваш конфиг. Это можно сделать через each, ссылку на который я вам дал выше.

Comment: Вот так пытаюсь сделать но результат тот же. $('.sliderBox').each(function (i, node) {
 $(node).slick({
  variableWidth: true,
  infinite: true, )}    Вот тут код  https://codepen.io/RJDio/pen/OJMBWxz

Comment: У меня все кнопки работают, из-за конфига слайдера не всегда виден эффект срабатывания.

Comment: $('.sliderBox').each(function (i, node) { $(node).slick({ variableWidth: true, infinite: true, )}   -- у меня только для последнего слайдера работают кнопки, и количество точек умножается на количество слайдеров. Если не сложно можешь выложить свой код ?

Comment: Сделал вот так, но единственное стрелки не могу добавить. --> $('.sliderBox').each(function (idx, item) {
    var carouselId = "carousel" + idx;
    this.id = carouselId;
    $(this).slick({
    variableWidth: true,
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 3000,
    dots: true,
        appendArrows: "#" + carouselId + " .sliderControl",
        prevArrow: '<a>Previous</a>',
        nextArrow: '<a>Next</a>'
    });
});

Comment: https://codepen.io/xydope/pen/xxZyqPX

Comment: Спасибо огромное.